# Java wait(), notifyall(), not working as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, wait

I have one Server which accepts multiple clients connections and performs the following operations

Client 1 transmits one line of information to the server, waits for the server side operation to complete 
Clients 2 Transmits one line of information to the server, waits for the server side operation to complete

Server when it has received information from both clients performs a certain operation, notify both the clients and again goes to wait state for both clients to transmit their line of information, but some how with the code i have written it seems not to be working in a proper way.

Server Code Snippet :

```
class ServerPattern extends Thread{
@Override
public void run() {

    try
    {
        while(moreData){

            if(clientId==1){
                synchronized (BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor){
                BaseStation.sourceAReadComplete = false;
                SourceARead.complete();
                BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor.notifyAll();
                }
            }
            else if(clientId==2){
                BaseStation.sourceBReadComplete = false;
            }
            //this.wait();
            synchronized(BaseStation.patternGenerationReadMonitor){
            BaseStation.patternGenerationReadMonitor.wait();
            }
        }
    }
    newSock.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Client Code Snippet :

```
class  sReadA extends Thread {

public static void serverJobComplete(){
    System.out.println("Source A Server job complete , Notifying Thread");
    synchronized(BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor){
        BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor.notifyAll();
    }
}

//public void readFile(){
public void run() {

    try {
        while((line = br.readLine())!= null){
            synchronized (BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor){
                if(BaseStation.patternGenerationComplete == true && BaseStation.sourceAReadComplete == false){
                        BaseStation.sourceAReadComplete = true;
                        BaseStation.sourceAReadMonitor.wait();
                    }
                    else if (BaseStation.sourceAReadComplete == true)
                    {
                        synchronized (BaseStation.patternGenerationReadMonitor){
                            BaseStation.patternGenerationReadMonitor.notifyAll();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
                    //ToDo : Wait for ServerSide Operation to Complete, later iterate till end of file
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

public class SourceARead {

```
public static void complete(){
    System.out.println("Complete Called");
    sReadA.serverJobComplete();
}

public static void main(String args[]){

    sReadA sAR = new sReadA(fName);
    sAR.start();

}
```

}

Comment: You want to use notify to notify the server from the client ? How could it work since they running on different process and even different machine ? Wait and notifyAll are used to synchronized tasks between threads not between client and server.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but how do i make these two different process wait for each other....

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe what is the problem you are facing with this.

You should use HTTP server port for this requirement. On server side open a server type of port and clients will connect to this port. java.net API can be useful for this.

You should not use wait/notify for this requirement as they are thread level control and they depends on the JVM implementation. All objects will have their thread wait list, once current running thread exits waiting threads are notified.

If this is your requirement then make sure that you are synchronizing on the correct object.

The wait notify or notify all is for multiple threads running under same JVM

BaseStation.patternGenerationReadMonitor.notifyAll(); will notify threads waiting for current object and not on BaseStation.

Hope this solves your problem